# What is the computational complexity of the first-order theory of real arithmetic?

Tags: space-complexity, first-order-logic

Tarski proved that the first-order theory of real-closed fields is decidable. Is the exact computational complexity known? The best upper bound I could find is EXPSPACE [1], where it is also conjectured to be EXPSPACE-hard.

Update: The complexity without multiplication, i.e., of FO$(\mathbb{R},+,<)$, is complete for the unusual complexity class STA$(*,2^n,n)$ [2]. This implies NEXPTIME-hardness.

Here STA$(s(n),t(n),a(n))$ is the class of problems solvable by single tape alternating TMs in space $s(n)$, time $t(n)$, and number of alternations $a(n)$, and a $*$ means no restriction.

[1] https://dblp.org/rec/journals/jcss/Ben-OrKR86

[2] https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(80)90037-7

Comment: You could go over all papers citing Ben-Or et al.

Comment: This seems a research-level question.

Comment: @xskxzr, That sounds plausible.  Were you thinking that this should affect how the question is treated?  (FYI, research-level questions aren't off-topic here -- I'm probably stating the obvious, though.)